# Pass audio file to function, rather than microphone data

Tags: node.js, audio

Might be a bit of a long shot, however I am using the google-assistant library with Node, and I want to pass this a recorded audio file, rather than use a microphone to record what I'm saying.

The example for mic input can be found here on line 55:
https://github.com/endoplasmic/google-assistant/blob/master/examples/mic-speaker.js

Does anyone know how I can go about using an audio file here, rather than a mic input?

Comment: You could try to pass your audio data to conversation `conversation.write(your_audio_data)`. How do you get your audio file ?

Comment: My audio file is just a .wav file, although can be in any format. Since I don't have a microphone on the device this is running on, I want to try and send some prerecorded audio to it (There is a reason I want to do it this way rather than using the Text input)

Comment: I mean how do you load your audio file into the frontend ?